# Apache y NGINX configurar subdominio

Tags: linux, apache, servidor, nginx, apache2

Tengo un servidor de pruebas con debian10 que he instalado **apache** y **nginx**.
En principio los tengo funcionando porque me devuelve tanto las páginas estáticas (html) como las dinámicas (PHP) si accedo a la IP externa del servidor.

Esto lo tengo en una máquina de OVH en el cloud con una ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
He entrado en el **panel DNS** de mi dominio y le he puesto un registro DNS de tipo A  a la ip de este servidor, con 
un nombre tipo **pruebas.midominio.com**

En dicho servidor he configurado e instalado **bind9**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     pruebas.midominio.com. root.pruebas.midominio.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      pruebas.midominio.com
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
@       IN      AAAA    ::1
```

Ahora si accedo desde mi pc local a pruebas.midominio.com apache me devuelve un 404 y en el registro del nginx veo lo siguiente

```
91.XXX.XXX.XXX - - [17/Jan/2020:16:46:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `VirtualHost` en `ServerName` pon el subdominio:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/ejemplo1"
    ServerName subdominio.ejemplo.com

    # Otras directivas
</VirtualHost>
```

Si OVH tiene un panel DNS no necesitas bind.
Considera también que la propagación de DNS puede tardar horas.

Comment: Perfecto , era eso gracias